# To include impl block inside cxx bridge

Tags: c++, rust, ffi

I'm trying to call a rust library from C++ using cxx bridge but faced this impl block that they didn't mention in demo code..

> Compiler error occurs when I'm trying to include, for example, impl C and functions in it inside mod ffi{} under #[cxx::bridge]. When I try this: `#[cxx::bridge] mod ffi { impl C { fn func1 -> C;} }`  Cargo warns me like this:

```
 error[cxxbridge]: expected an empty impl block
 ┌─ src/lib.rs:43:20
 │  


43 │       impl Locations {
     │ ╭────────────────────^
  44 │ │     /// Use the built-in cities.csv.
  45 │ │     pub fn from_memory() -> Locations {
  46 │ │         let mut records = Vec::new();
     · │
  77 │ │     }
  78 │ │     }
     │ ╰─────^ expected an empty impl block
```

> And If I try to include empty impl block C :  `#[cxx::bridge] mod ffi { impl C {} }` Cargo warns:

```
error[cxxbridge]: unsupported Self type of explicit impl
 ┌─ src/lib.rs:43:5
 │


 43 │     impl Locations {}
     │     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unsupported Self type of explicit impl
```

> Since I'm a newbie to Rust, I tried to ignore this impl block and include all function inside it in mod ffi{} but Cargo also refused that like this :

```
error[E0425]: cannot find function `from_memory` in module `super`
  --> src/lib.rs:47:12
   |
47 |         fn from_memory() -> Locations;
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `super`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0425`.
```

Here's the lib.rs of the library

```
#[cxx::bridge]
mod ffi{ struct A { // some code }
 struct B<'a> { // some code }
struct C { //some code }
struct D<'a> { // some code }
extern "Rust" {} } //this part is what I'm writing now 

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq)]
pub struct A { // some code }
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Clone)]
pub struct B<'a> { // some code }
pub struct C { member: xx, }
impl C { pub fn func1() -> C { //some code
C { member } } }
pub struct D<'a> { // some code }
impl<'a> D<'a> { //some code }

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
use super::*;
#[test]
fn test() { //some code }
```

I'll appreciate it if anyone gives me some sketch to fill the cxx bridge part.

Comment: Why? Just use one of them, don't mix these two. Anyways Rust and many other communities call C++ as unsafe.

Comment: @kiner_shah OP hasn't elaborated on their use-case but there's obviously times where some tool is written in language A but you want to / need to use it in language B. That's just a fact of the programming space unless you want to write absolutely everything yourself. And stop trying to pit language communities against each-other, this is not the place for inciting hostility.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem you're facing, or preferably, provide a concrete example that you want to get working? Are you getting a compiler error?

Comment: @kmdreko Well Thank you! I tried to specify the problem above, but you can ask me more details if you feel it's not enough.

Comment: And yes I changed objects' name as A, B, C to simplify but I'll change it to original code if it seems no clear thanks

Comment: @kmdreko, yeah I understand, will be careful going forwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide an `impl` block in a `#[cxx::bridge]` module. To provide a function from Rust you should put the declaration in the module but the definition in the parent module. Like this:

```rust
#[cxx::bridge]
mod ffi {
    struct Locations { /* some code */ }

    extern "Rust" {
        from_memory() -> Locations; // this declaration
    }
}

fn from_memory() -> Locations { // will use this definition
    todo!("put your implementation here");
}
```

You can do member functions by declaring the function with a parameter named `self` and thus use an `impl Locations { }` block, but you cannot provide C++ static member functions / Rust associated functions. See [this issue](https://github.com/dtolnay/cxx/issues/447) as the best reference I found that the syntax is not supported. You'd have to use a free function.

Comment: This helped a lot! Btw the discussion you shared seems not reflected to their current version.. that's why i cannot use impl block in cxx bridge. Thank you!